# Filter out string and numbers based on certain condition in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have my data -

| sl.no | category | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | 13 |
| 2 | no | unanswered |
| 3 | no | 10 |
| 4 | yes | 15 |
| 5 | no | 17 |
| 6 | no | unanswered |
| 7 | no | 9 |
| 8 | yes | 0 |

now i want to create a new column(#quant) where it should be - if in category column the number is greater than 15 it should be ">15", if less than equal to 15 then "<=15", if 0 then "0", and unanswered should be left as it is. So my final output will be -

```
sl.no  category   quantity      #quant(newly created column)
1        yes      13            <=15
2        no       unanswered    unanswered
3        no       10            <=15
4        yes      15            <=15
5        no       17            >15
6        no       unanswered    unanswered
7        no       9             <=15
8        yes      0              0
```

please help me to get the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want it as a dax Column.

```
#quant(newly created column) =
IFERROR (
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        VALUE ( 'Table (2)'[quantity] ) = 0, "0",
        VALUE ( 'Table (2)'[quantity] ) > 15, ">15",
        VALUE ( 'Table (2)'[quantity] ) <= 15, "<=15"
    ),
    'Table (2)'[quantity]
)
```

this only takes cells that contain strings that can be converted as values. if thats not possible, it returns the cell content.

Comment: Hey @Simon thanks a lot both of you for your reply

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [custom column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column) using this formula

```
if ([quantity] = "unanswered" or [quantity] = "0") then 
  [quantity]
else
  try
    if Int32.From([quantity]) > 15 then ">15"
    else "<=15"
  otherwise "not a number"
```

Like this

[image]

Which will give you the expected result:

[image]

It will check if `quantity` is `unanswered` or `0` and leave it unchanged in this case. Otherwise, it will try to convert the value to a whole number and check is it more than 15 or not. In case it is not a number, it will return `not a number`.